# Execute shell command from CouchDB function

Tags: couchdb

I'm looking for a way to execute a shell command from a couchdb function.

The only related information i found is this: https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/ExternalProcesses, but this method forwards all the query to and external process.

Answer (score 1):

it sounds silly - but even when there is a way I'd not use it. I think it would rather be about pursuing some other approach to integrate an external program's logic to deliver data to/from CouchDB. From the top of my head (maybe you want to elaborate on your use case a little bit):

- have a reverse proxy / business logic layer in e.g. nodeJS (the obvious one)
- use the _changes feed to poll for what comes into couch and feed it into your application (be aware however that CouchDB is not an MQ)
- use the _changes feed from before to update documents that still lack your program's input